# placing GradientDrawable in handler

Tags: android, background-color

I am trying to have background colour of an activity changing at runtime using the following code, but now I want to place it in a handler so till the activity remains active, the stroke colour moves ahead and changes the colour like it happens in Instagram app.

```
GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[] {0xFF616261, 0xFF131313});
    gd.setCornerRadius(0f);
    relativeLayoutMain.setBackground(gd);
```

Using this code, the background contains a white like stroke at the top with a black color.

Comment: I would try creating an Animatable Drawable instead of changing the Drawable on a View.

Comment: how to create Animatable Drawable?

Comment: take a look here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html. Or if you'll get a lot of frames I would try to extend a GradientDrawable, implement Animatable and apply logic for animating from AnimationDrawable sources.